# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource on localhost

Tags: json, api, angular, localhost

I'm trying to make a call to the Ebay API but it wont run on my local server. I get the following error;

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I've read something about JSONP and headers but I don't get it. Can anyone help me explain?

Code (angular2):

```
@Injectable()
export class PostsService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        console.log('PostsService Initialized...')
    }

    getPosts() {
        return this.http.get('http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=XXXXXkeyXXXX&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=processJSON&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=shoe&global-id=EBAY-GB')
            .map(res => <Post[]>res.json());
    }
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/JsonpModule-class.html

Comment: The server doesn't support being called from web applications that are not loaded from the same URL. The server needs to be reconfigured to support that. JSONP as mentioned by @anshuVersatile is a workaround. Another workaround is to make a request to your own server, that redirects to the ebay URL and returns the response to the browser. Only the browser checks for Access-Control-Xxxx headers. Servers don't care.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I understand the workarounds you are talking about. Although, I'm quite new to handling requests and still can't figure out how to make redirection request which should respond to my browser with the data. Any examples perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

The api you are trying to access is made up with `JSONP` so you need to access via jsonp call. JSONP is something like you add `script` tag in your html. And fortunately angular 2 has it's own jsonpmodule you can study it at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/JsonpModule-class.html